# Wouldn’t diode forward drop increases the cutoff voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, class-ab

This video seems to be a great explanation of class ab but the schematic shows diodes that should have a forward voltage of .7 plus the forward voltage of the base-emitter drop. He describes it as if it cancels the transistor v drop.

Am I missing something or is he just trying to illustrate “something” needs to be there.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YuVqccvgNPM

At 10:38 he describes the intention of the circuit.

Comment: Note that D1 in the schematic he shows is turned the wrong way, as Shahriar himself points out in the comments section. Does that make things clearer to you?

Comment: ok. That helps. Theoretically there needs to be voltage on the base for it to drop. Is the collector voltage on the base?

Comment: There are many errors on You Tube circuits.

Comment: Also there is no bias on those diodes, so it's not going to work anyway.

Comment: Ok. This is what I could not understand. Ultimately how do these diodes apply the required bias if they are not biased. 

Is there current between collector and base to forward bias them?

Comment: @Jonathan No, you would normally see resistors from the positive voltage to the top of the diodes, and from the negative to the bottom of the diodes such as you see here: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/amplifiers/class_ab_and_c_power_amplifiers.htm

Comment: With “YouTube circuits”, if they are not showing measurements on a working circuit, it’s best to assume the circuit will not work unless you know otherwise :/